# ComboBox don't allow empty value to the user

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want the user to not be able to select an "empty" choice from the ComboBox (drop down style). This can be done if the user deletes the text of the ComboBox with his keyboard. I have tried having a `SelectedIndexChanged` event and try to detect if the user sets the value to null and change it to `0` instead. BUT, this event doesn't trigger when the value is set to null (even after the user hits enter from his keyboard).

Any possible solutions ?

Comment: Don't have an empty option.

Comment: @depperm (Edited question) How can I do that ? He can always delete the text of the combo box with his keyboard

Comment: Do you want user to type into your box?

Comment: "I don't mind" is one thing, not needing it - another. Do you have so many items that user will be better typing it and searching in the list? If you can get rid of typing part  and move to drop down list, where user can only select - life will be easy

Comment: you need to block the user from changing the text inside the textbox itself, look very problematic... checking...

Comment: @T.S. No I don't have many items, therefore I don't need it. I suppose you are going to give me an answer which consists of disabling the keyboard on the `ComboBox`, which I would like to know. However I would like to know if this is possible without disabling the keyboard as well

Comment: No. Change style to `Drop Down List` and check for `selectedIndex`. `if selectedIndex > -1` --> item is selected. Use `selectedItem`. No need keyboard play. If you have empty value at index 0, check for selected index > 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [`DropDownStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your ComboBox to [`DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

[image]

and in your form's constructor add something like this:

```
yourComboBox.SelectedIndex = (yourComboBox.Items.Count > 0) ? 0: -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't** require a user to be able to type in custom values, you can change the drop down style to only allow the selection of items from your list. If you then set a default option, the user will never have an empty option selected.

For example:

```
comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I feel like this is the most useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have feeling that you, may be, struggling with UI logic. If you don't want to have empty items, than don't add one. But often it is useful to have an "empty item". One reason, if you have something selected for user, user just clicks "save" or something without changing that value and having wrong value.

Use `SelectedIndex` property to determine what selected during verification.

```cs
// init
cbo.comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
cbo.Items.Add("Select Letter") // first "empty" item
cbo.Items.Add("A")
cbo.Items.Add("B")
cbo.Items.Add("C")

// ---
void Save()
{
    if (cbo.SelecteIndex < 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select letter");
        return;
    }

    // "save" code here
}
```